# How to read multiple files and load them into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, path, glob

I have a list of csv's in a folder called 11 in C:\1.  All the data has same number of columns.

A.csv

```
aa    zz    1     AA  
aab   qq    3     FF
ca    qq    5     QQ
```

B.csv

```
aa    GG    09    VV
aab   HH    03    WW
ca    CC    0     UU
```

How do I read each file in that folder into the dataframe so that it has a empty column between each new data read from csv.

so that it looks like:

```
A     B     C     D     E    F     G     H     I
aa    zz    1     AA         aa    GG    09    VV
aab   qq    3     FF         aab   HH    03    WW
ca    qq    5     QQ         ca    CC    0     UU
```

I.e:

```
dfs = {i: pd.read_csv('C:\\1\\{}.csv'.format(i)) for i in ['a', 'b']}
print (dfs['a'])
```

Or:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
filelist = os.listdir(targetdir) 
df_list = [pd.read_table(file) for file in filelist]
big_df = pd.concat(df_list)


    FileNotFoundError: File b'b.csv' does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a spacer Data Frame on each file read, like this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# with directory name 1, located at ~/1:
dir_name = "1"
path = "~"
dfs = []

# with files A.csv, B.csv in ~/1 (e.g. ~/1/A.csv):
for fname in os.listdir(f"{path}/{dir_name}"):

    df = pd.read_csv(f"{path}/{dir_name}/{fname}", header=None)
    spacer = pd.DataFrame([" "]*len(df))
    dfs.append(df)
    dfs.append(spacer)
master = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

master
     0   1  2     3  0    0   1  2   3  0
0   aa  zz  1    AA      aa  GG  9  VV   
1  aab  qq  3    FF     aab  HH  3  WW   
2   ca  qq  5    QQ      ca  CC  0  UU
```

If you really want the alphabetical column names (`A`, `B`, `C`) you specified in your post, use:

```
import string
colnames = string.ascii_uppercase
master.columns = [x for x in colnames[:len(master.columns)]]
```

Note: Directory path uses Mac syntax, but it should be easy enough to adapt to Windows.

Comment: I seem to be getting pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 2

Comment: That usually happens either when you haven't specified the separator correctly for your CSVs, or when there are additional separators in a file, aside from the ones that actually separate columns.  For example, the way you presented A.csv in your original post, with multiple whitespace characters separating each field, will not work.  (I had assumed that was just for presentation, as you said they were CSVs, which denotes comma-separation.)  Check your separators, and make sure the `sep` argument in `read_csv` is correct.